# How does ApplyAsInt work automatically when a new instance of IntBinaryOperator is called?

Tags: java, string, int, overriding

I completed a programming excercise and then I checked other people's answers. I found one which I am facing difficulties to understand.

The excercise is: "Given a string of uppercase letters, for example ABC, return the number of letters missing"

```
ABC, returns 0
ABD returns 1, because C is missing
BCF returns 3, because A, D and E are missing.
```

---

```
import java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator;

public class TrainInspector {

    static class Op implements IntBinaryOperator {
        int prev = 'A';

        @Override
        public int applyAsInt(int left, int right) {
            left += right - prev - 1;
            prev = right;
            return left;
        }
    }

  public static int countMissingCarriages(String train) {
    if ( train == null || train.isEmpty() ) return 0;
    return train.chars().reduce(1, new Op());
  }

}
```

I understand that reduce gives us an int from the parameters given. However I do not understand how applyAsInt works automatically when a new IntBinaryOperator is created.

I have read:

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.util.function/IntBinaryOperator/index.htm

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-reduce-java-examples/

Comment: It works automatically because the reduce() method calls applyAsInt() on the IntBinaryOperator that you give it as argument.

Comment: The method take an `IntBinaryOperator`. `Op implements IntBinaryOperator`. Where is the confusion?

Comment: Now answers have been given, would mind voteup/accept one ? Or comments to ask for detail ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Her is the way it uses the `applyAsInt()` method

From [`abstract class IntPipeline`](https://java-browser.yawk.at/java/10/java.base/java/util/stream/IntPipeline.java#490)

```
@Override
public final int reduce(int identity, IntBinaryOperator op) {
    return evaluate(ReduceOps.makeInt(identity, op));
}
```

From [`final class ReduceOps`](https://java-browser.yawk.at/java/10/java.base/java/util/stream/ReduceOps.java#280)

```
static TerminalOp<Integer, Integer> makeInt(int identity, IntBinaryOperator operator) {
    class ReducingSink implements ... {
        private int state;

        //...

        @Override
        public void accept(int t) {
            state = operator.applyAsInt(state, t); // <----------
        }

        //...
    }
    return new ReduceOp<Integer, Integer, ReducingSink>(StreamShape.INT_VALUE) {
        @Override
        public ReducingSink makeSink() {
            return new ReducingSink();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The stream code is:

```
train.chars().reduce(1, new Op())
```

The javadoc of [`reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#reduce-int-java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator-) says:

> Performs a reduction on the elements of this stream, using the provided identity value and an associative accumulation function, and returns the reduced value. This is equivalent to:
>
> ```
>  int result = identity;
>  for (int element : this stream)
>      result = accumulator.applyAsInt(result, element)
>  return result;
> ```

To understand how `Op` is used here, let's look at the *equivalent* non-stream version of your `countMissingCarriages` method, by applying the code from the javadoc.

```
public static int countMissingCarriages(String train) {
    if ( train == null || train.isEmpty() ) return 0;
    
    // values from stream
    char[] stream = train.toCharArray();
    
    // values from 'reduce' parameters
    int identity = 1;
    IntBinaryOperator accumulator = new Op();
    
    // logic from javadoc
    int result = identity;
    for (int element : stream)
        result = accumulator.applyAsInt(result, element);
    return result;
}
```

Hope this helps clarify things.